# How do I diagnose hanging and restarts?

Tags: cyanogenmod, motorola-droid, reboot

I have a Droid which was running fine with Cyanogen Mod 6.0. I travelled for a week out of service range, and since I returned it's been both hanging (no response to user input) and spontaneously restarting.

I'm suspicious that an app update is causing this, but I don't know how to diagnose it. Is there a way to diagnose this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up spotting the offending program via Battery usage. There was one app that was showing a lot of battery use even though I wasn't doing anything with it (NewsRob). I killed that and everything's been fine since.

Comment: What do you use to see the detailed battery usage?  On my SGS the battery usage doesn't break it down by app.

Answer (score 2):

I would check `Settings` --> `Applications` --> `Running Services` first.

See anything there that looks rogue?  Consuming a lot of memory or the process seems hung up?

Comment: Thanks, that's a good place to look, but in my case nothing jumped out. Battery usage showed the problem.